Geometry Problem: Finding an Angle in a Right Triangle
I solve the problem using trigonometric functions and seek to understand alternative methods for solving it without relying on trigonometric functions.
The Problem:

Given a triangle △ABC with the following properties:
∠A=20∘
∠B=70∘
∠C=90∘
Draw the angle bisector of ∠A, which intersects side BC at point D.
Extend side AC beyond C to a point such that a line from B can be drawn, forming a 40∘ angle with BC.
Denote the intersection of this line with the extended AC as E (∠CBE = 40∘).
Draw a line segment ED.
find ∠DEC.


Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Thanks, I'll edit it.
